# I can not add new document in collection in firebase ( Cloud Firestore) using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to add document in collection in Cloud Firestore but it does not add
here is a code!

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
late final signInUser;  // this will give us user's email
String? messageText;   /// this will give us user's message


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "Chat"
  ),

  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Container(),

        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.orange,
                width: 2
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    messageText = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 10,
                      horizontal: 20
                    ),
                    hintText: "Write here ...",
                    border: InputBorder.none
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Send",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue[800],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  _firestore.collection('Messages').add({
                    'sender' : signInUser,
                    'text' : messageText,
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

when I clicked on send button This Message appeared

> `E/flutter ( 2417): #1      FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:121:13) E/flutter ( 2417): #2      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:463:9) E/flutter ( 2417): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13) E/flutter ( 2417): #4 StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:461:13) E/flutter ( 2417): #5      FirestoreMessageCodec.writeValue (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/firestore_message_codec.dart:121:13)`
> ` unitl #37

What should I do to solve this problem